# Pandas Dataframe: How to find the maximum value of a column and the date in which he value occurs in the date column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, max

The multi index pandas dataframe is the following:

```
                                    Full text Likes 
date        gap         time 
2018-05-22  -12.750000  04:20:51    ......     728
                        04:26:89    ......     675
                        04:43:32    ......     146444
```

Of course this is just part of the dataframe. 
What i want to do is to find the Tweet with the most likes, and find the date in whihc the tweet was posted and the gap of the day.

Comment: This could be what you want `df.loc[df.Likes == df.Likes.max()]`

Answer (score 0):

you can sort dataframe by using Likes column

```
df1=df.sort_values(by='Likes', ascending=False)   

print(df1.iloc[:1:,])
```